# Не понимаю как сделать открытие слайда, если выбрано определенное значение из select

Tags: javascript, laravel

У меня есть select с 5 значениями, и есть слайдер toggle. Мне нужно, чтобы при выборе 4(value="N2") или 5-го(value="N3") элемента тоггл открывал поля.
Как это лучше сделать?
Код select'a:

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" id="veh_type_code" autocomplete="off" name="veh_type_code" v-model="veh_type_code">
    <option value="L">Мотики</option>
    <option value="M1">Легковая тачка</option>
    <option value="N1">Грузовые, до 3.5т</option>
    <option value="N2">Грузовые, от 3.5т до 12т</option>
    <option value="N3">Грузовые, от 12т</option>        
</select>
```

Код слайдера

```
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggleOne"  onclick="$('#contentCard').slideToggle(function(){$('#toggleOne').html($('.contentCard').is(':visible')?'':'');});">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Т.е. как я строю цепочку:
Если не открыт слайдер -> если выбираются N2 или N3 —  происходит клик на чекбокс

Comment: непонятно, что Вы пытаетесь в input записать?

Comment: @ktscript, ничего не пытаюсь, мне нужно как-то сделать так, чтобы при выборе определенного значения слайдер открывался